# mpdf - images from a url won't load in generated pdf

Tags: php, yii, mpdf

I'm trying to load images from a `http` url but they won't display in my generated pdf.

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/pdftemplate';
$pdf = Yii::app()->toPDF->mpdf();
$pdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
$pdf->defaultfooterline = false;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../webroot/admin/themes/admin/css/formbuilder-print.css');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$pdf->WriteHTML($_POST['html_string']);
$pdf->Output(sys_get_temp_dir()."/test.pdf", 'F');
```

I'm passing the html to the php function in an ajax call. The images are on Amazon CloudFront.

**Update**

Thanks to Asped and Latheesan Kanes I got the issue resolved. I also used PHP's `DOMDocument` class to replace the image urls with the local copy of the image. This is for future reference if anyone also runs into a similar issue

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($_POST['html_string']);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagname('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img){
  $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
  $name = explode('?', basename($src));
  $name = $name[0];
  $tmp = sys_get_temp_dir().'/'.$name;
  copy($src, $tmp);
  $img->setAttribute('src', $tmp);
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML(); // you can write this to the pdf. $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: How are the images setup on your stylesheet? are they using full web root path? e.g. `/path/to/image.jpg` rather than relative path from the css file?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes The images are being loaded from a totally different url / web server. In my case from Amazons CloudFront

Comment: perhaps you might have to download the image to your local server in Yii's temp folder or something and replace the references to the amazon with the local temp location before you build the PDF. Try it with one image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue once displaying an SVG file in the pdf.. it would not work. Then I converted it to a PNG (on the fly), stored locally in a temp folder, and passed the temporary file to mDPF, which helped.

*UPDATE* - Actually now I remember I didn't even had to convert it, I just had to store it locally in a temp folder..

Comment: Copying the images from Amazon CloudFront to my temp folder solved the issue. I also used php's own `DOMDocument` to modify the html so the images would display. Thanks for the help.